# find common point inside different intervals

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Given a list of "threads", which contain 2 variables - starting and ending times - implement a function that will return all running threads at some time t. Optimize it.
(faster than O(n) )

---

My solution was to iterate through the list -- which is O(n). Does anyone know how to achieve faster than O(n) here?

```
class MyThread{
Thread thread;
long start;
long end;
}//the object in the list

//function to find "threads"
public List<Thread> matchingInterval(List<MyThread> list) {
    List<Thread> found = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    Set<Thread> runningThreads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    long instant = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(MyThread el: list)
        if(el.start <= instant && el.end >= instant && runningThreads.contains(el.thread))
            found.add(el.thread);
    return found;
}
```

EDIT:

The goal is to `return all running threads at some time t.` My solution assumes `time t` to be the time (plus/minus error) when my function is called, hence my `long instant = System.currentTimeMillis();` Is it possible that the caller specifies some arbitrary time? If yes, then I observe that the question really has nothing to do with threads per se and so I don't need to grab the actual `runningThreads`.

Another point: Just because a thread is alive, is it running?

Comment: Well, you will have to check every thread to see if its running, i.e O(n). The only way this could be a bit faster, would be if the list is pre-sorted according to the start times. Then you could do a binary search for the thread which has start time just greater than equal to time `t`.

Comment: Nothing was said about the list being sorted.

Comment: I thought about pre-sorting the list once, and then amortize the cost: since the list is pre-sorted, then all future calls to the function will find the list pre-sorted and will use binary search, costing O(2*lg n) which is O(lg n)

Comment: @kasavbere Sorting the list could be good/bad idea depending on the number of threads passed and looking at the function signature, it suggests that the list is passed to the function all the time. So, sorting once and using it out of question. The answer you provided is fine.Do think it can be made any faster.

Answer (score 1):

If your list is sorted, you can achieve faster than O(n) with any search algorithm (e.g. divide and conquer). Can't achieve faster than O(n) for an unsorted list since you have to look at each item

Comment: Nothing was said about the list being sorted.

Comment: @kasavbere it also doesn't say who maintains the list of threads. If you have access to how that list is being populated, then you can improve on the function. Otherwise there is no way to get it faster than O(n)

Comment: `Given a list of "threads"` seems to suggest I don't control the list.  If some client object that I don't control must use my function thru some API call, then I don't see the better than O(n) complexity. Otherwise, if my object has a local copy of the list, then as I mentioned above, amortizing the cost by pre-sorting is as far as I can see. up vote for trying.

Answer (score 0):

If they say "optimize it", that implies (to me) that you are allowed to preprocess the list  order to speed up future queries. In that case, I would use an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) (which is really just an application of a binary search tree).

Comment: Between Start time and end time, when is a thread considered running? I see the interval tree idea, but just because a thread is alive is it running?

Comment: It"s a very simple question. Given a list of intervals and a point, find out which intervals contain the point. Nothing more. There's nothing in there about subtle differences between "alive" and "running" and "existing" and "working" and whatnot